# Reading a single file using 3 thread

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io

i want three thread reading the single file for example the size of the file is 900 kb i want the first thread read the file 1kb to 300 and in the same fashion the other thread do (2 thread read from 301 kb to 600 kb AND 3 thread read 601kb to 900kb) does this approach make reading faster output has to be shown on the console may be the output get mixed it does not matter for me The main matter is that how to read the faster as comparison to single thread plz plz give me a suggestion or coding if somebody have plz

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547209/java-multithreading-reading-a-single-large-file ?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that if your goal is performance, you should not bother reading a single megabyte file in several threads. Most of the time is probably spent in doing the actual IO operation, that is reading from the disk (recall that disk operations are millions times slower than memory operations). Of course, on some occasions, it could be faster (e.g. on Linux system, the file data could have been cached, it it has been read or written some time before).

But when reading (rather small, i.e. megabyte sized) files, most of the time is spent in the system, and your coding won't impact that.

And reading a megabyte file should go fast on today's machines. You might use some dirty system tricks to improve it (e.g. the [Linux readahead system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/readahead)), if absolutely necessary.

Actually, your question surprises me. Reading one megabyte is quick today!

Comment: You are right. There are some special situations (SSDs, RAIDs, very large data sets), where it might help, but not for only 1 MB which takes only a few ms at most. When only a single disk is available, multithreaded reads will makes things always worse. A disk is a inherently single-threaded medium.

Answer (score -2):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
//
String filePath = args[0];

//Create runnable objects



//Load the file
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
//share this object among threads you want
MyFileReader mf1 = new MyFileReader(br);
MyFileReader mf2 = new MyFileReader(br);
MyFileReader mf3 = new MyFileReader(br);

new Thread(mf1).start();
new Thread(mf2).start();
new Thread(mf3).start();
//code to detect thread ends
//close br here

}


public class MyFileReader implements Runnable{

private BufferedReader br=null;

public MyFileReader(BufferedReader br){
this.br = br
}

public void run(){
String line=null;
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
//do your thing here e.g.
System.out.println(line);
}   
}
```

Comment: This is a recipe for disaster. You are not even guaranteed to get individual lines right.